# "Sequence contains no matching element" on ToList()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a piece of code that should retrieve a `List` of `User` objects.

```
public List<User> GetUsersBySessions(string[] sessionStrs, string ip)
{
    if (sessionStrs == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        return new List<User>();
    using (var ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        var ret = ctx.Sessions.Include("User").Where(s => sessionStrs.Contains(s.ID) && s.IP.Equals(ip)).Select(s => s.User).ToList();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The arguments `sessionStrs` and `ip` are properly passed into the method.  However, I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [imgbomb.com](https://i.imgbomb.com/lqaaT.png))</sub>

How could this type of error be caused when I'm not using any `.First()` or `.Single()`?  I'm just trying to get all items in a table that fit into an array return them as a `List`.  I've never seen such a problem before.

The following line of code even causes an error:

```
var ret = ctx.Sessions.ToList();
```

Here is my `DataContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericDataContext()
        : base(CONNECTION_STRING) //My CONNECTION_STRING is defined somewhere else, but I'm going to hide that for security's sake.
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

And here is my `Session` model:

```
[Table("tbl_Sessions")]
public class Session
{

    [Column("SessionID")]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Column("UserID")]
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Column("IP")]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    [Required]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

**NOTE**
Both `Classes` are properly namespaced and have their proper `using` statements, as well.

Comment: May be `sessionStrs` is `null`

Comment: I used breakpoints.  It's not.  It's a `string[]` with two values, each of which are proper SessionIDs in the database.  I should be getting TWO matches.

Comment: I suspect the USer Table does have matching entries.   Which results in a tolist issue

Comment: I just tried making a method that just returned all items in `ctx.Sessions`, not including `User`.  Go the same error.  Is it my `Model`?

Comment: Can you post some code for your `DataContext`?

Comment: I'll post a bit of it.

Comment: Posted my `DataContext` and my `Session`.

Comment: this is interesting, could you try adding `.Tolist()` after `Include` or after `Where` (ignore the rest of the code), and see whether any of it causes error.

Comment: I did `ctx.Sessions.ToList()` and I got the error just doing that.

Comment: It's trying to set the user when the context is loaded up.  Are you sure there is a user for each session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to this question had to do with the fact that one of my `models` had two `Keys`, each of which was a `string`.  When I changed said `model` to have an `int` as it's `Key`, all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

May be sessionStrs is null:

```
public List<User> GetUsersBySessions(string[] sessionStrs, string ip)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        var ret = ctx.Sessions.Include("User");
        if(sessionStrs!=null && sessionStrs.Any())
           ret =ret.Where(s => sessionStrs.Contains(s.ID));
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
           ret =ret.Where(s => s.IP.Equals(ip));

        return ret.Any()?ret.Select(s => s.User).ToList():NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question to include a null check.  It still does not work, same error, just two lines down now (but same content on that line).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have elements before selecting:

```
var ret = ctx.Sessions.Where(s => sessionStrs.Contains(s.ID) && s.IP.Equals(ip));
if (ret.Any())
    return ret.Select(s => s.User).ToList();
else
    return null; // or new List<User>();
```

Comment: Actually, I got the error on the line that first creates `var ret`.

Comment: I removed the include, please execute this code and tell us if you got the same or another exception and how line.

Answer (score 0):

Google led me here, so I'll throw my experience out there for anyone having a similar issue.

My project was using EF fluent configuration to query an existing database. I couldn't figure out why I was receiving any data back despite being able to query the table with other tools.

After banging my head against the wall, I finally discovered that I'd *mislabeled* the column type like so:

```
Property(x => x.DateCreated)
    .HasColumnName("datetiem") // strings are the devil
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` if you're extracting something from a list.